# Why eclipse preference general->workspace->refresh using native hooks or polling not working?

Tags: eclipse, vim, cygwin

I'm using vim in cygwin writing javascript code, using eclipse tomcat as web server. I checked the preference `refresh using native hooks or polling`. But after I write the buffer in vim, the project won't get refreshed, so the hosted application won't get republished neither. Only after I press F5 on the project manually, then everything works fine. Can someone help here? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

By default, Vim writes the file contents to a temporary file and then moves that over the original, see `:help backup`. Since this is now a different file (handle), the hooks set up by Eclipse may stop working.

You can make Vim override the original file by setting

```
:set backupcopy=yes
```